# Matrix notation $i$ $j$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, index-notation

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a_1       & a_2 & \cdots & a_n \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ be a $n \times n$ matrix such that $a_i \cdot a_i = 1$ for all $i$ and $a_i \cdot a_j = 0$ for all $i \neq j$.

I'm familiar with $i$ indicating row and $j$ indicating column but I'm not sure what these dot products actually refer to.

Let's say we have $B = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt2}       & \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\
    -\frac{1}{\sqrt2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\ \end{bmatrix}$.

What does $a_i \cdot a_i =1$ and $a_i \cdot a_j = 0$ mean here?

Comment: Inner products?

Comment: It's a [dot product in this sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Algebraic_definition)

Answer (score 2):

In this case the $a$’s are the columns of the matrix, so $a_i\cdot a_j$ is the dot product of its $i$th and $j$th columns.

Comment: Ok, the elements in the matrix is actually supposed to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Does this mean that $a_i \cdot a_j$ is the first column (viewed as a vector) dotted with the second column (viewed as a vector)? (we only consider the example B)

Comment: Well, specifically $a_1\cdot a_2$ is the first column dotted with the second, but it looks like you’ve gotten the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Such $B$ doesn't fulfill your constraints. Perhaps you intended$$B=\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}&-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\\\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}&\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\end{bmatrix}$$here we define $$a_m=\begin{bmatrix}b_{1m}\\b_{2m}\\.\\.\\.\\b_{nm}\end{bmatrix}\qquad,\qquad \forall m$$and $$a_i\cdot a_j=\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_{ki}b_{kj}$$

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not like $i$ is for rows and $j$ is for columns. In your case $a_i, a_j$ are both column vectors:

$$
a_i =\left[\begin{matrix} 
a_{1,i} \\
a_{2,i} \\
\ldots \\
a_{n,i} \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

So the notation
$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a_1       & a_2 & \cdots & a_n \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ is equivalent to:

$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
{\left[\begin{matrix} 
a_{1,1} \\
a_{2,1} \\
\ldots \\
a_{n,1} \\
\end{matrix}\right]} 
&
{\left[\begin{matrix} 
a_{1,2} \\
a_{2,2} \\
\ldots \\
a_{n,2} \\
\end{matrix}\right]} 
&
\ldots
&
{\left[\begin{matrix} 
a_{1,n} \\
a_{2,n} \\
\ldots \\
a_{n,n} \\
\end{matrix}\right]}
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \dots & a_{1,n} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \dots & a_{2,n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \\
a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \dots & a_{n,n} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and the product $a_i \cdot a_j$ means just a standard dot product of two vectors.

Comment: I still don't get what $a_i \cdot a_i$ means. Why is $a_i \cdot a_i = 1$ for all $i$ in my example?

Comment: In your example $a_i \cdot a_i = a_{1,i}^2 + a_{2,i}^2 \;$. So for $i=1$ we have 
$(\frac{1}{\sqrt2})^2 + (-\frac{1}{\sqrt2})^2 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1\;$. Similarly for $i=2$.

Comment: Why do you square the $a_{1,i}$ and $a_{2,i}$?

Comment: Oh nvm, I got it. Thank you for the assistance

Comment: See [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913485/matrix-notation-i-j/2913513?noredirect=1#comment6018417_2913485) by @Omnomnomnom. In your case $n=2$, so $a_k \cdot a_l = a_{1,k} a_{1,l} + a_{2,k} a_{2,l}$. What happens if $k=l$?

Comment: So the idea is that $a_i \cdot a_i$ is the first entry in the first row squared and then we add the first entry in the second row squared?

Why don't you just get $a_i \cdot a_i = a_{1,1} * a_{2, 1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} * \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} = -1$ ?

Comment: Why do I get $-1$ when the constraint says $a_i \cdot a_i = 1$?

Comment: Just look at the definition. You have two vectors, for each pair of their corresponding components multiply them and finally add all these products together. (Anyway $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} * \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \neq -1$)

Comment: What do you mean by each pair of their corresponding components? Even though I have two vectors in my matrix, we only look at the first one : $[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}]$ right? Because $i = 1$

Comment: Ok, so I looked up the definition of an inner product, I haven't learned any of this yet so I'm sorry for the simple questions that I should know the answer to.

I think I got it now. Since $i=1$ we're only dealing with the first column-vector: $[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}]$. If I transpose it and multiply by itself (definition) then your calculations make sense, finally.